# Floating Action Buttons in fragment eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I'm trying to implement `FAB` in eclipse. I found this code [here](https://gist.github.com/Jogan/9def6110edf3247825c9).

But the following code is not working in fragment `onCreateView` method(I tested and it works in activity's onCreate method).

```
FloatingActionButton fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
        .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_add))
        .withButtonColor(Color.WHITE)
        .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)
        .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
        .create();
```

How to implement to work in a fragment. Please help this.

Comment: what problem you are facing in that?

Comment: @vrundpurohit as I mention in the question above whole code contain errors.

Comment: have you add the fab library?

Comment: Can you refer [this](https://gist.github.com/roberdcr/ef33471fb8bd47165540) instead ?

Comment: I tried the add design support library in to eclipse project I tried as every thing in 1st page of googling. But it is unsuccessful for my project. This method is to create fab without library. This shows errors using in fragments. @SohailZahid

Comment: Are you able to import `FloatingActionButton ` Class?

Comment: Check given link in the question. I used that. As I said I didn't add fab in lauout or import classes. only plain code.(Because design support libraray didn't worked on my eclipse project.) If you know working way to import that class in eclipse or correcting above code please help me soon as possible. @SohailZahid